# Activites not being shared

Tags: sharing, activities, partner-communities

I have an issue where activites are not being shared as I understand they should be.

First off the OWD is set to Controlled by Parent.

We have a community with partner users, there are tasks related to a custom object which are created by a user which are assigned to another user however the creating user can't see the tasks despite having created them and having access to the parent record.

Am I misunderstanding how activities are shared, in which case can someone explain it and how to achieve what I want.
Is there some other setting I should be looking at.

Thanks

Comment: Is the user also owner of the parent record? Based on following documentation https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187772&type=1 community user can only see Activities that he owns. In Master-detail relationship child inherits Owner from parent record.